# intValue method not found

Tags: java

```
I have made a programme to count the number of words using HashMap.Here it is-:


import java.util.*;
class Count{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String in=s.nextLine();
        HashMap hm=new HashMap();
        String sh[]=in.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<sh.length;i++){
            String key=sh[i];
            if(sh[i].length() > 1){
                if(hm .get(key)==null){
                    hm.put(key,i);
                }
                else{
                    int value=new Integer(hm.get(key).intValue());
                    value++;
                    hm.put(key,value);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hm);
    }
}
```

But in this programme I am getting error that .intValue() symbol not found as I am using jdk 1.6 a feature of autoboxing and unboxing is added so I guess that is the problem.I want to calculate the count so Please give me the solution.

Comment: On the side not, words should be your keys, and the number of words should be your values...

Comment: Response in there, but you don't need to create a new Integer ...

Comment: yes, if you are using JDK6, you could use generics, aka new HashMap<String,Integer>() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this code.

```
int value=new Integer((Integer)hm.get(key)).intValue();
```

Or better

```
int value = (Integer)hm.get(key);
```

Comment: it is not really missing a ), but rather it is misplaced. :)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `hm.get(key)` is an object and `Integer` doesn't have constructor that takes `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize your map: use `HashMap<String, Integer>` instead of `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

this way you don't need to convert map value to int. It is "converted" automatically:

```
int value= hm.get(key);
value++;
hm.put(key,value);
```

Also usually you don't declare you variables as concrete implementation like `HashMap` but rather use generic `Map` interface:

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `HashMap` which does not specify what types of objects are stored inside.
To specify what are stored inside, you need to use generics.
Define hashmap as `HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`
Otherwise, everything stored inside will be considered as just `Object` and an `Object` does not have an intValue method. So the error is thrown by compiler.